# Internal Microphone not capturing input

Tags: 16.04, alsa

The Internal microphone on dell Precision 7510 is successfully detected on Ubuntu 16.04, however it does not capture any input.

From others thread I tried editing the alsa-base.conf file to include different models to no avail.

Using pavucontrol also was not successful.

```
aplay -l Output is as follows:

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3235 Analog [ALC3235 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

while the content of /proc/asound/cards is:

     0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                          HDA Intel PCH at 0xdd348000 irq 130
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Open `Sound Setting` on `System Settings` open `input` tab see
what sound card is installed if any exists, click it
speak on `Microphone`
if Right side bar show any change 
your Microphone is installed and Work.

Comment: The Microphone is mentioned inside the Input tab, however it does not register any input. (IE, when I talk the microphone does not capture the input)

Comment: report the full name of your microphone(s) that is list in input tab. if there are two or more select it and test